# Concurrency issue with Spring Integration - "Cannot publish to a deleted Destination"

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have two applications running either side of an ActiveMQ broker; application 1 sends synchronous requests to application 2 which returns the response back to application 1.

**Application 1**

```
@MessagingGateway
public interface OrderGateway {

    @Gateway(requestChannel = "requestChannel", replyChannel = "responseChannel")
    public OrderDto fetchOrder(OrderRequest orderRequest);
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow outgoingRequestFlow(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {

    return IntegrationFlows.from("requestChannel")
                           .handle(Jms.outboundGateway(connectionFactory).requestDestination("order.queue"))
                           .get();
}
```

**Application 2**

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow incomingRequestFlow(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {

    return IntegrationFlows.from(Jms.inboundGateway(connectionFactory).destination("order.queue"))
                           .channel("requestChannel")
                           .handle("orderServiceActivator", "fetchOrder")
                           .channel("responseChannel")
                           .get();
}

@Component
public class OrderServiceActivator {

    @Autowired
    OrderService orderService;

    @ServiceActivator
    public OrderDto fetchOrder(OrderRequest orderRequest) {

        return orderService.getById(orderRequest.getId());
    }
}
```

Both applications contain the following broker connection factory config:

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "stop")
public PooledConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory() {

    ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
    activeMQConnectionFactory.setBrokerURL("tcp://broker.local:61616");

    return new PooledConnectionFactory(activeMQConnectionFactory);
}
```

I have created a REST controller in application 1 `/myapp/order/{id}` which submits a request to `orderGateway.fetchOrder`, which is working fine. I then tested it by running `while true; do curl http://localhost:8080/myapp/order/1; done` at the command line and left it running for several minutes, which sent hundreds of requests through the app, no errors, everything was fine. I can see that `request.queue` is enqueuing and dequeuing the messages in the ActiveMQ admin tool, and `ActiveMQ.Advisory.TempQueue` also has a high enqueue/dequeue count.

The problem occurs when there are concurrent requests; if I open up two terminal windows and run the curl-loop in both windows, very quickly I start to see the following errors:

```
Sep 21, 2015 4:35:25 PM org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer invokeErrorHandler
WARNING: Execution of JMS message listener failed, and no ErrorHandler has been set.
javax.jms.InvalidDestinationException: Cannot publish to a deleted Destination: temp-queue://ID:Stans-MacBook-Pro.local-64816-1442849675850-1:1:559
```

Is my SI configuration wrong? Are there some other configuration parameters I need to apply? Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 1):

I'd need to see a debug log from both sides to figure out what's happening - it implies the client side has timed out; the default timeout is 5 seconds, however. You can increase the `receiveTimeout` on the outbound gateway.

That said, it's generally better to use a named reply destination, to avoid creating a temporary reply queue for each request. Bear in mind that the same timeout applies there too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Gary. I'm going to focus on creating a named reply destination to see whether the error still persists. I've created a separate question about this instead of editing this one.